# Versioning of reports in reporting services (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, report, version

It is not the first time this question has been asked, but no solution has been found yet. The only thread I found somewhat relevant was this but it is 4 years old: [SSRS Reports Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068144/ssrs-reports-versioning)

Perhaps a solution has been found since then?

Back to my questions:
I have several reports in a Visual Studio solution (BIDS). From here I can deploy to several reporting servers: Test1, Test2 and Production.

1) It seems that the granularity of deployment is: Reports, Datasets and Datasources. This can be setup in Properties for the solution. But I want to be able to only deploy a single report, if I only have changes to one report. How do I do this? As it is now it seems that I have to deploy ALL reports.

2) Since I have more than 1 place to deploy there is a possibility of the reports getting out of sync. Normally the procedure would be to deploy the reports to Test until everything is fine, and thereafter deploy to Production. But since this is a manual process something can go wrong. Therefore I believe it would be nice to have some sort of versioning on the individual reports. But I can find no way of doing this? I'm thinking that it would be really nice if a timestamp and/or versionnumber could be set on the reports when they are deployed. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Currently running into this problem!

Answer (score 2):

How about putting the version number of the report on the report itself? You would need to run the report to see it though.

To deploy a single report, right-click on the report name and **Deploy** to deploy that report (or dataset or data source).

As far as the deployment issues, you can use version control such as **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turns out that there IS a "Deploy" menu item in the context menu, when clicking on a single report, but it is placed in the lower third of the context menu whereas it is placed in the upper third when clicking on the Solution. Thanks for pointing that out.


I'm not sure what you mean by the version number on the report itself?
I'm using Mercurial as sourcecontrol BTW.

Comment: Since SSRS doesn't have a built-in global **version** variable, I thought you might be able to just include the report **version number** on the report itself. Then you could compare the current report's version number with the version that's deployed on a server to ensure that it's up to date. It's not automated but at least there's something that works.